# cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30005 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Tags: wordpress

I set up WordPress locally on my Computer with local wp and now want to create a static file with simply static to host my website on Firebase for free but this error appears:

> "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30005 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

I checked the site health and also found this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just switching from local wp to bitnami